# Reverse function not entirely replacing everything

Tags: python

Write a function ReverseComplement to solve the Reverse Complement Problem, which is reproduced below. (Hint: use the function reverse that you wrote on the last step as a subroutine.)

Need a little help here! I need to change a given text not only backwards but also making some letters equal to others in order to generate a whole new result:

```
def reverse(text):
        reversed_text = ""
    # Note: Indices are starting with zero and the last number in ranges aren't included
    for i in range(len(text)):   
        reversed_text += text[len(text)-1-i]
    return reversed_text

text = 'AGCTTTTCATTCTGACTGCAACGGGCAATATGTCTCTGTGTGGATTAAAAAAAGAGTGTCTGATAGCAGC'
text = text.replace('A', 'T')
text = text.replace('G', 'C')
```

So my output would print:

```
CCTCCTTTCTCTCTCTCTTTTTTTTTTCCTCTCTCTCTCTTTTTCCCCCTTCCTCTCTCTTTCTTTTCCT
```

But the real thing that I need to do whit my function is:

```
GCTGCTATCAGACACTCTTTTTTTAATCCACACAGAGACATATTGCCCGTTGCAGTCAGAATGAAAAGCT
```

Not entirely replacing the A for T and G for C.... I have 0 programming experience and I`m stuck! please Help

Comment: What _is_ "the real thing" you're trying to do?

Comment: text.replace('A', 'T') replaces all 'A's with 'T's. So TAT -> TTT. What you need to do is text.replace('A', '1'), text.replace('T', 'A'), text.replace('1', 'T').

Comment: I`m trying to make a function so I can reverse the text that I input but also at the same tame replace it so I can have the result I'm expecting. Thing is not using only .replace just like that, I have to make a function so I can incorporate that into my reverse function

Comment: So I need to make any other function and make it like a subroutine inside my reverse function. @TigerhawkT3

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it:

```
text[::-1].translate(maketrans('ACGT', 'TGCA'))
```

This uses:

- `text[::-1]` to reverse the string
- `maketrans` to create a translation table
- `translate` to perform the actual translation

---

Snippet for **Python 2**:

```
from string import maketrans

text = 'AGCTTTTCATTCTGACTGCAACGGGCAATATGTCTCTGTGTGGATTAAAAAAAGAGTGTCTGATAGCAGC'
translated = text[::-1].translate(maketrans('ACGT', 'TGCA'))

print(translated)
```

---

Snippet for **Python 3**:

```
text = 'AGCTTTTCATTCTGACTGCAACGGGCAATATGTCTCTGTGTGGATTAAAAAAAGAGTGTCTGATAGCAGC'
translated = text[::-1].translate(str.maketrans('ACGT', 'TGCA'))

print(translated)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you can reverse the whole string by using:

```
def reverse(string):
    return string[::-1]
```

or

```
''.join(reversed("AGCTTTTCATTCTGACTGCAACGGGCAATATGTCTCTGTGTGGATTAAAAAAAGAGTGTCTGATAGCAGC"))
```

Then, you'll need to replace the letters

text.replace('A', 'T') will replace all 'A' with 'Ts. So TAT -> TTT.
What you need to do is text.replace('A', '1'), text.replace('T', 'A'), text.replace('1', 'T').

example:

```
text = 'AGCTTTTCATTCTGACTGCAACGGGCAATATGTCTCTGTGTGGATTAAAAAAAGAGTGTCTGATAGCAGC'
# For swapping A and T
text.replace("A", "1")
text.replace("T", "A")
text.replace("1", "T")

# For swapping G and C
text.replace("G", "1")
text.replace("C", "G")
text.replace("1", "C")
```

Comment: Yes but what I need is to make a function that can make that without using replace. The idea is to make that all in one single shot using 2 functions

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the easiest way to reverse a string would be

```
text = "ACGT"
reversed_text = text[::-1]
# Now, reversed_text is "TGCA"
```

Once you've done that, you can replace A with T and C with G (and vice-versa)

```
# For swapping A and T
reversed_text.replace("A", "1")
reversed_text.replace("T", "A")
reversed_text.replace("1", "T")

# For swapping G and C
reversed_text.replace("G", "1")
reversed_text.replace("C", "G")
reversed_text.replace("1", "C")
```